# How to get data from MYSQL to HTML form with INPUT TEXT field to fill some data to store back in database with respective field in table using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, vb.net, excel

This is my first time in asking a question.
where every time i am getting a solution with the previous answers and i cant find any solution for my problem.

Here I am having a data in mysql table named "class_master" which consists of some data in columns with in some multiple rows

Here we are having some headings in class master (columns)

```
 2. Class master id
 3. Noun
 4. Modifier_1
 5. Modifier_2
 6. Modifier_3
 7. Sap_Class_id
 8. Sap_Class_Description
 9. Sap_Attribute_Description
10. Sap_Atrribute
11. Attribute_Description
12. Sequence
13. Total no of attributes
```

For example if item is a valve.

```
 - **HEADING**              **Row data**
 - Noun                      :valve
 - Modifier1                 : ball
 - Modifier2                 :Metric
 - Modifier3                 :-- (N/A)
 - Sap_Class_id              :ME_BA_VALVE
 - Sap_Class_Description     :METRIC BALL VALVE
 - Sap_Attribute_Description :C901854_TYPE,SIZE,MAT,GRADE ETC.., (EACH
   IN SEPARATE ROW AND NUMBER OF ROWS WILL DIFFER BASED ON ITEM)
 - Sap_Atrribute             :SAME AS ABOVE
 - Attribute_Description     :SAME AS ABOVE
 - Sequence                  :ROW SEQUENCE NUMBER FOR EACH ITEM
 - Total no of attributes    :TOTAL NUMBER OF ATTRIBUTES OR ROWS IN THIS
   ITEM
```

NOW WHEN I NEED TO GET THE "sap_class_description" TO MY HTML FORM BASED ON "sap_class_id" with an empty text box parallel to it to enter the respective values and after submitting it i need them to store in another table named as "class" .

class master is having the data for arround 1000+ items (fields to fill).
as a template
class table is for storing the output for each item with respective id to store the values filled in that template.

Here i am attaching the sample output in excel as a screenshot.

i am having around 10000+ items and each item is having a different attributes with different count(rows).
Based on the item i have to find the right "class_id" with respect to the "NOUN", MODIFIERS".
With this class id i need to copy the relative attributes and then i have to fill them with the specifications in that input text field.
after that i need that to be saved in my "class" table with respect to the ID number which i am getting from $_GET['id'].

Please help me to get this.
For any further info please let me know

**Class master backup in excell**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/dSc7g.jpg

**class master output**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D9Y7.jpg